# Symfony2 Many To Many not saving on merge in a fixture

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I developed some Fixtures in Symfony2 to work like crons that will be launch every 5-10 minutes. Thats becuase me application depends on a external api that is continuosly changing.

On the other hand, the api have a complete unrelated and no sense json responses and i cant trust all the data is comming in every call, so i have many nullable fiedls than can be updated on next cron "maybe". I want to treat it and store in a related database:

I have:

```
class Hero
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="heroes")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="heroes_roles")
   **/
  private $roles;
}

class Role
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Hero", mappedBy="roles")
   **/
  private $heroes;
}
```

And in me fixture, after connect with the api and get data from json:

```
// Roles
$rolesRepository = $manager->getRepository('ProjectStoreBundle:Role');
$rolesIndexedByName = $rolesRepository->getIndexedBy('name');

// Json con info de los heroes
$heroesInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->kernel->locateResource('@ProjectStoreBundle/Resources/doc/heroes_info.json')));

foreach ($array_response['result']['heroes'] as $apiHero) {
   $hero = new Hero();
   $hero->setId($apiHero['id']);
   $hero->setName($apiHero['name']);
   ...// more normal sets

   // Update it if exists
   $manager->merge($hero);

   // Add his roles
   foreach ($heroesInfo->$apiHero['name']->roles as $role) {
        if (!empty($rolesIndexedByName[$role])) {
           $hero->addRole($rolesIndexedByName[$role]);
        }
   }
}
$manager->flush();
```

Things i tried:

1. Change the order, first add roles, then merge
2. Add inverse on $hero->addRole
3. Put cascasde {persist}

Option 2:

```
public function addRole(Role $roles)
{
    $roles->addHero($this); // cascade error
    $this->roles[] = $roles;

    return $this;
}
```

I maybe forgive something, im learning symfony2 at time i develop the application.

Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**

If i change merge for persists, the many to many relations are saved, but i cant use same script to update then.

Someone can explain me why merge is not creating relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution days ago, forgive to answer the question:

I change just this piece of code:

```
// Update it if exists
$manager->merge($hero);

// Add his roles
foreach ($heroesInfo->$apiHero['name']->roles as $role) {
    if (!empty($rolesIndexedByName[$role])) {
       $hero->addRole($rolesIndexedByName[$role]);
    }
}
```

To this:

```
// Update it if exists
$mergedHero = $manager->merge($hero);

// Add his roles
foreach ($heroesInfo->$apiHero['name']->roles as $role) {
    if (!empty($rolesIndexedByName[$role])) {
       $mergedHero->addRole($rolesIndexedByName[$role]);
    }
}
```

And it flush all the data correctly.

Hope it helps someone.